# PHP error_log function not working after upgrading to IIS 7.5

Tags: php, iis, web.config

I'm using [`error_log`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php) which has been working fine for years under IIS 6. Recently I upgraded to IIS 7.5 (Windows 7) and the messages logged by `error_log` stop appearing.

In fact nothing is going to the log. If I call an incorrect function to force a *real* PHP error, it gets reported to the screen, but not to the file. My ini settings:

```
display_errors=On
error_log='C:\Work...\php_errors.log'
log_errors=on
error_reporting=E_ALL & !E_DEPRECATED
```

I've also added `< httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />` to the web.config file in my virtual directory but it doesn't work even after a restart.

Can anyone shed any light?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem eventually turned out to be access permissions for the folder where the error log was.  I had to give the IUSR user write access to that folder.

Al.

Comment: And remember googlers --   IUSR not II_IUSR :)

Comment: @Userpassword, It's `II_IUSRS` not `IUSR`. `IUSR` didn't work for me, tested on win server 2012.

Comment: @AlHenderson, It's the **file** that needs write access, not the folder. (But setting folder will work too because the file will inherit permissions upwards.)